Pyspark Structed Streaming with applyInPandasWithState method latency issue
I am writing a Stateful Structured Streaming application in Pyspark (Spark version 3.5) and making use of applyInPandasWithState. I've noticed a drastic degradation in processing speed compared to Pyspark's native groupby function. The function applied in conjunction with it simply increments the group state values by 1 (this is to avoid any user-defined logic errors). I am unable to understand why the use of applyInPandasWithState seems to be adding a huge overhead in time, apparently making the computations heavy (all the executors cores were being fully utilized).
The function call after groupby.
finalDF = callList.groupby("KEY").applyInPandasWithState(
    length_fn, 
    outputStructType="id string, value string",
    stateStructType="LEN long", 
    outputMode="Update",
    timeoutConf=GroupStateTimeout.NoTimeout)

The function being called
def length_fn(key, pdf_iter, state):
    state_len = 0    
    if state.exists:
        state_len = state._value["LEN"] 
    state_len += 1

    yield pd.DataFrame({"id": [key[0]], "value": [str(state_len)]})`

Any input would be much appreciated. Thanks
